# Why can't Reflector show byte arrays? Is this due to some technical limitation?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflector

I want to see the contents of a byte array, but Reflector don't show them. Why? Is this due to some technical limitation, or is just a feature not implemented by Reflector?

Is there any other tool which I can use to do this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ask Redgate. Your question has nothing to do with actual code.

Comment: Agree with leppie, question doesn't belong here, but maybe try Just Decompile from telerik

Comment: I disagree with leppie and Nick - it's a valid question, one that I'm sure a lot of people have had at one time. When you initialize a field in your code, it does show up in the ..cctor (or .ctor for instance fields) method, as Frederic's answer reveals - this tells you something about how your C# code gets compiled, and is helpful when using any disassembler.

Comment: This is *definitely* programming related. Check the FAQ if you're curious why. Even if it were just about Reflector, it would be on topic. But it's *also* asking about the [possible] technical limitations involved, *and* what software could be used to do this. Keep the finger off that close button trigger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Static members are initialized in the class' static constructor as far as the CLR is concerned.

If you disassemble the `.cctor()` method, you should see the assignment to `myname`.

Answer (score 1):

does this byte array initialized, cause I suppose you're reading a declaration of an array ? 
Declaration is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find the code that assigns the byte array contents.  Given the member list visible in the tree, I'm guessing you'll find it in the static constructor (.cctor).